# Can't use certain methods when extending SortedList

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a class that extends SortedList. I can use the many of the SortedList methods in my class like Add() and Remove() but for some reason it doesn't like it when I try to use GetKey(). Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

```
public class SymbolTableImplementation : SortedList<string, SymbolTableEntry>, SymbolTable
{
    public SymbolTableEntry Enter(string name)
    {
        SymbolTableEntry entry = SymbolTableFactory.CreateSymbolTableEntry(name, this);
        Add(name, entry);  // This is OK
        return entry;
    }

    //  Look up an existing symbol table entry. Null if it does not exist.
    public SymbolTableEntry Lookup(string name)
    {
        return GetKey(name);  // Doesn't exist in current context
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for not telling us what you mean when you say "doesn't like this"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetKey` is defined in `SortedList`, which is actually a completely separate class from `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`.   You also have a mistake in your original code; if you *were* actually using `GetKey`/`SortedList`, this would not have compiled:

```
return GetKey(name);
```

Instead, just use the `IDictionary` indexer:

```
return this[name];
```

Comment: Well crud. I totally didn't notice that there were two different types of SortedList. That explains why it wasn't working.

Comment: Alright, `return Keys[name];` doesn't work. It says 'cannot convert from string to int.'

Comment: Okay, now it's saying: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Interpreter.intermediate.SymbolTableEntry'.

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize `SortedList` was a dictionary, and thus to get the value from the key requires just ordinary dictionary indexer access.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, that's what I needed. However I also needed it to return `null` instead of throwing an exception if the key didn't exist so I ended up doing this: `return (ContainsKey(name) ? this[name] : null);`

Answer (score 2):

There is no method with name `GetKey` in `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` class.

Answer (score 2):

No GetKey(), that's already clear.  The proper implementation is:

```
public SymbolTableEntry Lookup(string name)
{
    return this[name];
}
```

Which should give you pause, the method is superfluous.  The indexer of SortedList is already good enough to get the job done.  So just remove this method, the user of this class won't be able to guess which one to use.

Note that there's a similar problem with Add() vs Enter().  Nothing good will happen when the client programmer uses Add().  What you really want to do is *replace* or hide the Add() method but that's not possible.  You can overload it but that's as far as that can go.

The .NET collection classes are not really designed to be derived from, their methods are not virtual.  They work better if you *encapsulate* them, creating your own collection class that only inherits, say, IDictionary and use a private SortedList to get the job done.  That's a fair amount of work but it will be squeaky clean.

Comment: Yeah, hadn't realized it was a dictionary.  Nice catch!